# WebScraping - Get the CAPTCHA ,set by Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

This might be a trivial question, sorry if it is. But i have tried searching for answers, and couldn't get a convincing one.
I recently visited a website which required login, and saw that it set the CAPTCHA using the following JS code:

```
function Captcha(){
          var alpha = new Array('A','B','C','D',.....,'1',...,'9');
          var i;
          for (i=0;i<4;i++){
          var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
          var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
          var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
          var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
          var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
          var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
          var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
          }
          var code = a + '' + b + '' + '' + c + '' + d + '' + e;
          document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code
```

}

There is a tag with id as "mainCaptcha" in the main body.

```
<input size="10" name="autocap" id="mainCaptcha" readonly="">
```

Since all this happens on the client-side, i think it should possible to get the CAPTCHA value through a script.Please suggest a way to do so , if it is possible.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain which legitimate reasons you have for trying to bypass a CAPTCHA?

Comment: @CodeGruzzler The website is of my telecomm service provider.
Moreover the question is just for my curiousity, i want to know if its possible, since i feel their way of generating CAPTCHA's is not the best way possible. :)

Comment: @Shubham12 - I think the lock on your front door is not the best possible, so I'm going to ask on locksmiths.stackexchange.com for ways to pick it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value` to retrieve the value of the CAPTCHA. This is a very insecure way of implementing a CAPTCHA. So do the right thing and notify the owner of the website about this very poor CAPTCHA implementation.

Comment: This method works only if i could add code to the html doc.
i wanted to know if it is possible to do it externally.

Comment: Well, obviously, you will need some kind of browser emulation for that. You can try phantom.js

Comment: developer console should do the job

Answer (score 0):

This is the most insecure method of using Captcha reason is very simple captcha is used to add extra layer of security. You can secure your site using distorted images which are not directly available to hacker/scraper. I would suggest go ahead with best practices either generate images at your server and relay to client or try out [Google reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/java)

or any other captcha generation tool

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
     <head>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function Captcha(){
                 var alpha = new Array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
                 var i;
                 for (i=0;i<6;i++){
                   var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                   var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                   var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                   var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                   var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                   var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                   var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
                  }
                var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
                document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code
              }
              function ValidCaptcha(){
                  var string1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('mainCaptcha').value);
                  var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
                  if (string1 == string2){
                    return true;
                  }
                  else{        
                    return false;
                  }
              }
              function removeSpaces(string){
                return string.split(' ').join('');
              }
         </script>    
    </head>
 <body onload="Captcha();">
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
             <h3>Text Captcha 'Yashpal Thakur'<h3><br />
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="text" id="mainCaptcha"/>
          <input type="button" id="refresh" value=" Please Refresh" onclick="Captcha();" />
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtInput"/>    
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Please Check" onclick="alert(ValidCaptcha());"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```